# Tomcat customization while starting server

Tags: tomcat8

I am manually copying a war file to the web-apps folder of Tomcat and starting Tomcat using `cmd ./catalina.sh start`. I want to customize it in such a way that I can use a war name to start e.g `./catalina.sh start quickenweb` (where 'quickenweb' is a war file name).

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: you can stop or start application using the manager, you can also config the server.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to Windows and WinZip or the 7-Zip File Manager, you can open the war file with Zip Program.  Or, if you have LINUX, PeaZip/File Roller would work too.

In the zip program, you can navigate to the folder - like log4j.properties for example and edit it.  When closing TextPad/LeafPad for example, the Zip program should prompt you to update the war file.  It is advisable to edit/update the war file outside of the tomcat folder structure and then delete the war under tomcat and then update..  Actually, probe is a great tool for managing/updating/compiling war files.

Hope this helps?